# QuickSight Embed add Domain with https://localhost

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have localhost with https and now I want to add this domain into QuickSight Dashboard to use Embed feature, but I have this error: This Domain is not supported. QuickSight dashboards can only be embedded in valid https domains. What is the best practice for us to testing QuickSight Embed in development environment ? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quicksight requires that dashboard access be from https and allowed domains.

Add the domains(s) you'll be using as allowed domains via Manage Quicksight / Domains and Embedding. These need to include the port number if it's not the standard one. For example, I added something like `https://dev.company.net:4200`

To make your local requests appear to come from this host, add this to your local /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.company.net
```

I used [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) to create a locally-trusted development certificate, so that I can access my local server via https.

Then, go to your local server via https://dev.company.net:4200 (with your own domain and port).

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted if you're all set.

Comment: Why doesn't adding something like "https:// localhost/*" to QuickSight allowed domains work?