# AWS QuickSight Vue app Embed add domain with http://localhost

Tags: vue.js, amazon-quicksight

I'm having trouble with connecting QuickSight dashboard to our Vue app (development), because it only accepts https urls. How do I make the Vue app run so that it would be https? Didn't get it to work with these instructions. [QuickSight Embed add Domain with https://localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878401/quicksight-embed-add-domain-with-https-localhost/65829069#65829069)

Comment: you could use a reverse-proxy like NGINX to add https.

Comment: Why is it made so complicated?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried myself by whitelisting `http://localhost:3000` (not httpS!), and it worked. No need to setup a self-signed certificate and https.

Of course you'll need to adjust to the port you're using locally (I'm using 3000).

The domain needs to be added in the ["Domains and Embedding"](https://eu-central-1.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/sn/admin#embedding) tab of the AWS Quicksight settings.